# Unable to run the automation test case in mac using appium

Tags: java, ios, xcode, macos, appium-ios

I am trying to run the appium script on mac but facing the issue when running the script. Details are mentioned below:

**Configuration:**

```
OS: 10.13.6
xcode: 9.4.1
Simulator : iPhone 7
Java_client jar = 6.1.0
Okhttp jar = 3.9.1
httpclient jar = 4.5.3
appium server = 1.8.1
```

**Steps:**
I have added the following desired capabilities  in my script:

```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 7");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/synerzip/Desktop/emulator/Concishare Provider.app");
  capabilities.setCapability("usePrebuiltWDA", false);
 capabilities.setCapability("clearSystemFiles", true);
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
 capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTO_WEBVIEW, true);
        IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

**Error:**

When I am trying to run it, it is displaying the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'syn-macmini-03.synerzipune.local', ip: '2001:df0:d300:212:a155:8262:1823:7137%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
```

I have added the java client jar with version '5.0.0' but still getting the same error

Comment: Found https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/926.  Might have some help there.

Comment: I have updated the single capability as follow: IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http:/127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities); after updating I have restarted my machine and it start working, I don't know what magic is happen. @RKelley: Thanks for looking in to it